# jquery datepicker flicker issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I enable following options

```
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
```

clicking on button/input field causes whole or a part of page to clicker. It happens only in FF. Any idea what is going on?

Thanks, Pawel

Comment: Do you have a url so we could test it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :/ I'll try to publish only that one page tomorrow. Anyway, could it have something to do with <select> elements, which are enabled by changeMonth, changeYear options?

Comment: I've uploaded one page with that issue. It filckers in FF 3:
http://aspspider.net/dragonflypl/index.aspx

Comment: And here is the kicker: it flickers in latest version of FF (3.6.3). In previous one I had, 3.5.9 there was no flickering effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to upload one page with that issue. Could you please take a look:
[Flickering datepicker](http://aspspider.net/dragonflypl/index.aspx)

EDIT: Apparently it's FF bug:

[Bug ticket on jQuery UI](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5493)
[Bug post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-flickering)